# IKImageView and scroll bars

Tags: objective-c, macos, scroll, ikimageview

I have an NSScrollView with an IKImageView inside to display images. This seems to work.

However, if I make the window smaller than the image, the scrollbars appear as they should, but the BOTTOM of the image is locked to the bottom of the window, instead of the top of the image being locked to the top of the window. In other words, I want the image to not move on the screen when I re-size the window from the bottom right.

I understand why this is, because in All of these classes, the origin is in the lower left, not the upper left. However, It's still behaving wrong. If you look at any other product (including Preview, which I assume is written with some of these libraries) the image/content/whatever, is locked to the top not the bottom.

How do I do this?

I've looked for methods in the NSScrollView and IKImageView. I've considered capturing the scroller events and manually moving the image down or up as appropriate, but I haven't seen a way to do this (Set the selector to a method I write in the controller?) and anyway, that seems very messy...

Is there an easy way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for future reference:
   Make a subclass of IKImageView with only one over-ridden method:

```
-isFlipped()
{
   return YES;
}
```

This subclass will also prove useful if I find that I need to re-implement the rotate:(id) method and the setImage:(NSImage) method which exist in the class (and in the case of rotate are USED IN THE DEMO supplied by Apple) but not documented, and therefore not officially supported...